# Pod link L<Module::Subfile> does not link to lib/Module/Subfile.pod

Tags: perl, dist-zilla, metacpan

I use Dist::Zilla for the CPAN distribution https://metacpan.org/pod/ODF::lpOD_Helper.

The distribution includes two files with pod documentation:

```
lib/ODF/lpOD_Helper.pm
lib/ODF/lpOD_Helper/Unicode.pod
```

The pod in lpOD_Helper.pm contains references to the Unicode.pod file like

```
See L<ODF::lpOD_Helper::Unicode>
```

When installed, `perldoc ODF::lpOD_Helper::Unicode` displays the Unicode.pod content.

However clicking the links in the html shown at metacpan do not work.  The `L<ODF::lpOD_Helper::Unicode>` pod link is translated to an html link containing URL `https://metacpan.org/pod/ODF::lpOD_Helper::Unicode` (no .suffix), which gets a 404 error -- no such page.

Similar links **do** work in other distributions.  For example ODF::lpOD 's main documentation page https://metacpan.org/dist/ODF-lpOD/view/lpOD.pod contains links like

```
L<ODF::lpOD::Tutorial>
```

which, when rendered on the metacpan page, is a link containing url `https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/ODF-lpOD/lpOD/Tutorial.pod` (with a .pod suffix) which works (presumably the web server translates or maps URLs ending in .pod to html).

**How does pod-to-html and/or metacpan correlate L<...> links in pod to .pod files in the distribution?**  Do I need to provide some meta information about the file, and if so how to do it via Dist::Zilla?

Comment: No idea if this is the issue, but try changing the name section to be of the form `ODF::lpOD_Helper::Unicode - ...` (or at least start with `ODF::lpOD_Helper::Unicode`)

Comment: Thanks for the idea.   It works now.  Besides that change, I added a META.json using Dist::Zilla::Plugin::MetaJSON (there used to be only META.yml), so not sure exactly what the fix was.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was resolved after I added META.json (formerly only had META.yml), and put the fully-qualified module path as the first thing in the NAME section of the vanished .pod -- *thanks ikegami for the suggestion in your comment!*

I don't know which of these was responsible, and it seemed like the META.json contained no information which was not in the META.yml; but now the Unicode.pod page is correctly linked to at https://metacpan.org/pod/ODF::lpOD_Helper

(Since I'm using Dist::Zilla, I added [MetaJSON] to dist.ini and install Dist::Zilla::Plugin::MetaJSON)